# Change doxygen format of function signatures in the generated HTML

Tags: html, c++, doxygen

I use [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl) to document C++ code. In the current project, I use the following format for function signatures:

```
MyClass(MyClass&& other)
```

However, in the generated HTML documentation, the brief description has this signature:

```
MyClass (MyClass &&other)
```

and the detailed description has this signature:

```
MyClass ( MyClass && other )
```

Is there a way of either preserving the original format, or changing the way doxygen formats the signatures? I have not found anything related to this issue in the [customization](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html) or [configuration](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html) pages.

Edit: Updated the signatures based on the discussion in the comments.

Comment: I don't get quite the same thing as you. I get `MyClass (MyClass &&other)`. So I only get space between the function name and the parentheses, not between the parentheses and the argument type/name, nor the between the reference symbol and the argument name. What version of doxygen are you using?

Comment: @JohnPerry: I use version 1.8.10. I have made a [screenshot](https://img42.com/YLjxk) of the generated HTML.

Comment: I, too, am using 1.8.10. That suggests at least some of these things are customizable. Are you using default settings?

Comment: I have created a sample Doxygen documentation from scratch, using default settings ([screenshot](https://img42.com/5Kxpv)). As you can see, there are two occurrences of the function (brief and detailed descriptions). You were referring to the first one. I was referring to the second one. What I would like is to have in both cases this: `void func(int* a)`. Basically, my question is whether the format of the signatures in the resulting HTML can be modified.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: **No.**

Long (and more correct) answer: Yes, if you're willing to modify the source code.

- File `memberdef.cpp` has the following (line 1668 in what I'm looking at today):

  ```
  // *** write arguments
  if (argsString() && !isObjCMethod())
  {
    if (!isDefine() && !isTypedef()) ol.writeString(" ");
  ```

  That last line is going to add space in the brief description. (I've verified this by removing it and recompiling.)
- As for the detailed description, that sets up a table, with `<td>(</td>` opening the arguments list. You might get rid of that space more easily, but doing it well will probably require monkeying with the source code.

I guess the best option is to roll your own, or to request a feature addition from the developers.